# Group by hour showing breakdown for each day within date range MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to create a query to show the breakdown of leads relating to finance contracts grouped by hour.

Here's an example of what I have so far for hours:

```
SELECT CONCAT(HOUR(received), ':00-', HOUR(received)+1, ':00') AS Hours, 
COUNT(*) as `leads`
FROM (digital_lead)
WHERE `received` BETWEEN '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-24 00:00:00'
GROUP BY HOUR(received)
```

And here's the result ....

```
 Hours   usage

0:00-1:00   36
1:00-2:00   25
2:00-3:00   16
3:00-4:00   4
4:00-5:00   7
5:00-6:00   8
6:00-7:00   13 // etc all the way to 23:00 - 24:00
```

OK - so that seems to work, however, it aggregates all of the `leads` for that time slot over the course of the period set in the `BETWEEN` statement. I would like to be able to show the breakdown per hour for each day within the period range.

So that would look something like:

```
Date        Hours         leads
2014-11-01      
            0:00-1:00      36
            1:00-2:00      25
            2:00-3:00      16
            3:00-4:00      4
            4:00-5:00      7
            5:00-6:00      8
            6:00-7:00      13 // etc all the way to 23:00 - 24:00
```

So each date would be displayed and then the hours for that day and so forth.

Thanks.

Comment: do you also want to show zeros in case an hour is not present on a particular day?

Comment: @fthiella - If possible I would like to show the zero results per hour too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by date as well:

```
SELECT DATE(received), HOUR(received), ...
...
GROUP BY DATE(received), HOUR(received)
```

Since you're grouping by hour() only, you'll essentialy be getting

```
Hour
1      sum of leads in hour 1 of jan 1, jan 2, jan 3, ... dec 31
2      sum of leads in hour 2 of jan 1, jan 2, jan 3, ... dec 31
```

Rather than

```
Jan 1  Hour 1  sum of leads for just that one hour on the one day
Jan 1  Hour 2  sum of leads for just that one hour on the one day
..
Dec 31  Hour 23 sum of leads
```

Comment: Thanks Marc - that's helped a lot. Could I apply the same approach to grouping by day, week, month and year?